# My fragments keep recreating whenever I reclick or navigate to the next fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have implemented the new architecture component on my android app, but unfortunately handling the states of these fragments has become a nightmare for me. Whenever I press the icon of the fragment, the fragment is recreated every time I navigate. How can I handle this or rather save these fragments states?

Here is my main activity handling the five fragments:

```
public class MainActivityCenterofInformation extends AppCompatActivity {

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_maincict);

        setUpNavigation ();
    }

    public  void setUpNavigation(){
        bottomNavigationView = findViewById (R.id.bottom_nav_cict);
        NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment)getSupportFragmentManager ()
                .findFragmentById (R.id.nav_host_fragment_cict);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController (bottomNavigationView, navHostFragment.getNavController ());
    }

    //adding animations to the fragment
}
```

I can't read Kotlin so please direct me to Java, thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> **TL;DR:** skip to the ***JUST SHOW ME THE STEPS ALREADY !!!*** section

That is the normal behaviour of the fragments. They are suppose to be recreated every time they are removed or replaced and you are suppose to restore their states using `onSaveInstanceState`.

Here is a nice article that describes how to do it : [Saving Fragment States](https://evanhalley.dev/post/saving-fragment-states/)

Other than that you can use [View Model](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI3bKX-pmm5gIVyOFRCh0-Zg6EEAAYASAAEgLhsPD_BwE) which is the part of the following recommended android architecture. They are a great way to retain and restore UI data.

You can learn how to implement this architecture by following this step by step [code lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-livedata-viewmodel/#0)

[image: Android recommended architecture]

**EDIT : *Solution***

> ***Note :** The solution assumes one doesn't wants to use `ViewModels` and simply wants to hide or show fragments using the Navigation UI*

It covers the following points

- Keeping fragment alive during navigation
- Implement custom navigation behavior on back key press ***(Optional)***

**Background :**

Android Navigation component has a `NavController` class that you can use to navigate to different destinations. `NavController` uses a `Navigator` that actually does the navigation. `Navigator` is an abstract class and anyone can extend/inherit it to provide custom navigation depending on the type of destination. When using fragments as destinations the `NavHostFragment` uses a `FragmentNavigator` whose default implementation replaces the fragments whenever we navigate using `FragmentTransaction.replace()` which completely destroys the previous fragment and adds a new fragment. So we have to create our own navigator and instead of using `FragmentTransaction.replace()` we will use a combination of `FragmentTransaction.hide()` and `FragmentTransaction.show()` to avoid fragments from being destroyed.

**Default behavior of Navigation UI :**

By default whenever you navigate to any other fragment other than the home fragment they won't get added to backstack so lets say if you select fragments in the following order

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E
```

your back stack will have only

```
[A, E]
```

as you can see the fragments B, C, D weren't added to backstack so pressing back press will always get you to fragment A which is the home fragment

**The behavior we want for now :**

We want a simple yet effective behavior. We wan't all fragments to get added to backstack but if the fragment is already in backstack we want to pop all fragments upto the selected fragment.

Lets say I select fragment in following order

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E
```

the backstack should also be

```
[A, B, C, D, E]
```

upon pressing back only the last fragment should be popped and backstack should be like this

```
[A, B, C, D]
```

but if we navigate to lets say fragment B, since B is already in the stack then all the fragments above B should be popped and our backstack should look like this

```
 [A, B]
```

I hope this behavior makes sense. This behavior is easy to implement using global actions as you will see below and is better than the default one.

**OK Hotshot! now what ? :**

Now we have two options

1. extend `FragmentNavigator`
2. copy/paste `FragmentNavigator`

Well I personally wanted to just extend `FragmentNavigator` and override `navigate()` method but since all its member variables are private I couldn't implement proper navigation.

So I decided to copy paste the entire `FragmentNavigator` class and just change the name in entire code from *"FragmentNavigator"* to whatever I want to call it.

**JUST SHOW ME THE STEPS ALREADY !!! :**

1. Create custom navigator
2. Use custom tag
3. Add global actions
4. Use global actions
5. Add the custom navigator to the NavController

**STEP 1: Create custom navigator**

Here is my custom navigator called `StickyCustomNavigator`. All the code is same as `FragmentNavigator` except the `navigate()` method. As you can see it uses `hide()` , `show()` and `add()` method instead of `replace()`. The logic is simple. Hide the previous fragment and show the destination fragment. If this is our first time going to a specific destination fragment then add the fragment instead of showing it.

```
@Navigator.Name("sticky_fragment")
public class StickyFragmentNavigator extends Navigator<StickyFragmentNavigator.Destination> {


    private static final String TAG = "StickyFragmentNavigator";
    private static final String KEY_BACK_STACK_IDS = "androidx-nav-fragment:navigator:backStackIds";

    private final Context mContext;
    @SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess") /* synthetic access */
    final FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    private final int mContainerId;
    @SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess") /* synthetic access */
            ArrayDeque<Integer> mBackStack = new ArrayDeque<>();
    @SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess") /* synthetic access */
            boolean mIsPendingBackStackOperation = false;

    private final FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener mOnBackStackChangedListener =
            new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {

                @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
                @Override
                public void onBackStackChanged() {
                    // If we have pending operations made by us then consume this change, otherwise
                    // detect a pop in the back stack to dispatch callback.
                    if (mIsPendingBackStackOperation) {
                        mIsPendingBackStackOperation = !isBackStackEqual();
                        return;
                    }

                    // The initial Fragment won't be on the back stack, so the
                    // real count of destinations is the back stack entry count + 1
                    int newCount = mFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() + 1;
                    if (newCount < mBackStack.size()) {
                        // Handle cases where the user hit the system back button
                        while (mBackStack.size() > newCount) {
                            mBackStack.removeLast();
                        }
                        dispatchOnNavigatorBackPress();
                    }
                }
            };

    public StickyFragmentNavigator(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull FragmentManager manager,
                           int containerId) {
        mContext = context;
        mFragmentManager = manager;
        mContainerId = containerId;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBackPressAdded() {
        mFragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(mOnBackStackChangedListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBackPressRemoved() {
        mFragmentManager.removeOnBackStackChangedListener(mOnBackStackChangedListener);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean popBackStack() {
        if (mBackStack.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (mFragmentManager.isStateSaved()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Ignoring popBackStack() call: FragmentManager has already"
                    + " saved its state");
            return false;
        }
        if (mFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            mFragmentManager.popBackStack(
                    generateBackStackName(mBackStack.size(), mBackStack.peekLast()),
                    FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            mIsPendingBackStackOperation = true;
        } // else, we're on the first Fragment, so there's nothing to pop from FragmentManager
        mBackStack.removeLast();
        return true;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public StickyFragmentNavigator.Destination createDestination() {
        return new StickyFragmentNavigator.Destination(this);
    }

    @NonNull
    public Fragment instantiateFragment(@NonNull Context context,
                                        @SuppressWarnings("unused") @NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager,
                                        @NonNull String className, @Nullable Bundle args) {
        return Fragment.instantiate(context, className, args);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public NavDestination navigate(@NonNull StickyFragmentNavigator.Destination destination, @Nullable Bundle args,
                                   @Nullable NavOptions navOptions, @Nullable Navigator.Extras navigatorExtras) {
        if (mFragmentManager.isStateSaved()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Ignoring navigate() call: FragmentManager has already"
                    + " saved its state");
            return null;
        }
        String className = destination.getClassName();
        if (className.charAt(0) == '.') {
            className = mContext.getPackageName() + className;
        }

        final FragmentTransaction ft = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        int enterAnim = navOptions != null ? navOptions.getEnterAnim() : -1;
        int exitAnim = navOptions != null ? navOptions.getExitAnim() : -1;
        int popEnterAnim = navOptions != null ? navOptions.getPopEnterAnim() : -1;
        int popExitAnim = navOptions != null ? navOptions.getPopExitAnim() : -1;
        if (enterAnim != -1 || exitAnim != -1 || popEnterAnim != -1 || popExitAnim != -1) {
            enterAnim = enterAnim != -1 ? enterAnim : 0;
            exitAnim = exitAnim != -1 ? exitAnim : 0;
            popEnterAnim = popEnterAnim != -1 ? popEnterAnim : 0;
            popExitAnim = popExitAnim != -1 ? popExitAnim : 0;
            ft.setCustomAnimations(enterAnim, exitAnim, popEnterAnim, popExitAnim);
        }

        String tag = Integer.toString(destination.getId());
        Fragment primaryNavigationFragment = mFragmentManager.getPrimaryNavigationFragment();
        if(primaryNavigationFragment != null)
            ft.hide(primaryNavigationFragment);
        Fragment destinationFragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
        if(destinationFragment == null) {
            destinationFragment = instantiateFragment(mContext, mFragmentManager, className, args);
            destinationFragment.setArguments(args);
            ft.add(mContainerId, destinationFragment , tag);
        }
        else
            ft.show(destinationFragment);

        ft.setPrimaryNavigationFragment(destinationFragment);

        final @IdRes int destId = destination.getId();
        final boolean initialNavigation = mBackStack.isEmpty();
        // TODO Build first class singleTop behavior for fragments
        final boolean isSingleTopReplacement = navOptions != null && !initialNavigation
                && navOptions.shouldLaunchSingleTop()
                && mBackStack.peekLast() == destId;

        boolean isAdded;
        if (initialNavigation) {
            isAdded = true;
        } else if (isSingleTopReplacement) {
            // Single Top means we only want one instance on the back stack
            if (mBackStack.size() > 1) {
                // If the Fragment to be replaced is on the FragmentManager's
                // back stack, a simple replace() isn't enough so we
                // remove it from the back stack and put our replacement
                // on the back stack in its place
                mFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(
                        generateBackStackName(mBackStack.size(), mBackStack.peekLast()), 0);
                mIsPendingBackStackOperation = false;
            }
            isAdded = false;
        } else {
            ft.addToBackStack(generateBackStackName(mBackStack.size() + 1, destId));
            mIsPendingBackStackOperation = true;
            isAdded = true;
        }
        if (navigatorExtras instanceof FragmentNavigator.Extras) {
            FragmentNavigator.Extras extras = (FragmentNavigator.Extras) navigatorExtras;
            for (Map.Entry<View, String> sharedElement : extras.getSharedElements().entrySet()) {
                ft.addSharedElement(sharedElement.getKey(), sharedElement.getValue());
            }
        }
        ft.setReorderingAllowed(true);
        ft.commit();
        // The commit succeeded, update our view of the world
        if (isAdded) {
            mBackStack.add(destId);
            return destination;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public Bundle onSaveState() {
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        int[] backStack = new int[mBackStack.size()];
        int index = 0;
        for (Integer id : mBackStack) {
            backStack[index++] = id;
        }
        b.putIntArray(KEY_BACK_STACK_IDS, backStack);
        return b;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreState(@Nullable Bundle savedState) {
        if (savedState != null) {
            int[] backStack = savedState.getIntArray(KEY_BACK_STACK_IDS);
            if (backStack != null) {
                mBackStack.clear();
                for (int destId : backStack) {
                    mBackStack.add(destId);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    private String generateBackStackName(int backStackIndex, int destId) {
        return backStackIndex + "-" + destId;
    }

    private int getDestId(@Nullable String backStackName) {
        String[] split = backStackName != null ? backStackName.split("-") : new String[0];
        if (split.length != 2) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid back stack entry on the "
                    + "NavHostFragment's back stack - use getChildFragmentManager() "
                    + "if you need to do custom FragmentTransactions from within "
                    + "Fragments created via your navigation graph.");
        }
        try {
            // Just make sure the backStackIndex is correctly formatted
            Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
            return Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid back stack entry on the "
                    + "NavHostFragment's back stack - use getChildFragmentManager() "
                    + "if you need to do custom FragmentTransactions from within "
                    + "Fragments created via your navigation graph.");
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess") /* synthetic access */
    boolean isBackStackEqual() {
        int fragmentBackStackCount = mFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
        // Initial fragment won't be on the FragmentManager's back stack so +1 its count.
        if (mBackStack.size() != fragmentBackStackCount + 1) {
            return false;
        }

        // From top to bottom verify destination ids match in both back stacks/
        Iterator<Integer> backStackIterator = mBackStack.descendingIterator();
        int fragmentBackStackIndex = fragmentBackStackCount - 1;
        while (backStackIterator.hasNext() && fragmentBackStackIndex >= 0) {
            int destId = backStackIterator.next();
            try {
                int fragmentDestId = getDestId(mFragmentManager
                        .getBackStackEntryAt(fragmentBackStackIndex--)
                        .getName());
                if (destId != fragmentDestId) {
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid back stack entry on the "
                        + "NavHostFragment's back stack - use getChildFragmentManager() "
                        + "if you need to do custom FragmentTransactions from within "
                        + "Fragments created via your navigation graph.");
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @NavDestination.ClassType(Fragment.class)
    public static class Destination extends NavDestination {

        private String mClassName;

        public Destination(@NonNull NavigatorProvider navigatorProvider) {
            this(navigatorProvider.getNavigator(StickyFragmentNavigator.class));
        }

        public Destination(@NonNull Navigator<? extends StickyFragmentNavigator.Destination> fragmentNavigator) {
            super(fragmentNavigator);
        }

        @CallSuper
        @Override
        public void onInflate(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull AttributeSet attrs) {
            super.onInflate(context, attrs);
            TypedArray a = context.getResources().obtainAttributes(attrs,
                    R.styleable.FragmentNavigator);
            String className = a.getString(R.styleable.FragmentNavigator_android_name);
            if (className != null) {
                setClassName(className);
            }
            a.recycle();
        }

        @NonNull
        public final StickyFragmentNavigator.Destination setClassName(@NonNull String className) {
            mClassName = className;
            return this;
        }

        @NonNull
        public final String getClassName() {
            if (mClassName == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Fragment class was not set");
            }
            return mClassName;
        }
    }

    public static final class Extras implements Navigator.Extras {
        private final LinkedHashMap<View, String> mSharedElements = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        Extras(Map<View, String> sharedElements) {
            mSharedElements.putAll(sharedElements);
        }

        @NonNull
        public Map<View, String> getSharedElements() {
            return Collections.unmodifiableMap(mSharedElements);
        }

        public static final class Builder {
            private final LinkedHashMap<View, String> mSharedElements = new LinkedHashMap<>();

            @NonNull
            public StickyFragmentNavigator.Extras.Builder addSharedElements(@NonNull Map<View, String> sharedElements) {
                for (Map.Entry<View, String> sharedElement : sharedElements.entrySet()) {
                    View view = sharedElement.getKey();
                    String name = sharedElement.getValue();
                    if (view != null && name != null) {
                        addSharedElement(view, name);
                    }
                }
                return this;
            }

            @NonNull
            public StickyFragmentNavigator.Extras.Builder addSharedElement(@NonNull View sharedElement, @NonNull String name) {
                mSharedElements.put(sharedElement, name);
                return this;
            }

            @NonNull
            public StickyFragmentNavigator.Extras build() {
                return new StickyFragmentNavigator.Extras(mSharedElements);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**STEP 2: Use custom tag**

Now open up your `navigation.xml` file and rename the **fragment** tags related to your bottom navigation with whatever name you gave in `@Navigator.Name()` earlier.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home">

    <sticky_fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:name="com.example.bottomnavigationlogic.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

</navigation>
```

**STEP 3: Add global action**

Global actions are a way to navigate to destination from anywhere in your app. You can use the visual editor or directly use xml to add global actions. Set global action on each fragment with the following settings

- destination : self
- popUpTo : self
- singleTop : true/checked

[image]
[image]

This your how your `navigation.xml` should look like after adding global actions

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home">

    <sticky_fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:name="com.example.bottomnavigationlogic.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <sticky_fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_images"
        android:name="com.example.bottomnavigationlogic.ui.images.ImagesFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_images"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_images" />

    <sticky_fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_videos"
        android:name="com.example.bottomnavigationlogic.ui.videos.VideosFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_videos"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_videos" />
    <sticky_fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_songs"
        android:name="com.example.bottomnavigationlogic.ui.songs.SongsFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_songs"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_songs" />
    <sticky_fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
        android:name="com.example.bottomnavigationlogic.ui.notifications.NotificationsFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_notifications"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_notifications" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_navigation_home"
        app:destination="@id/navigation_home"
        app:launchSingleTop="true"
        app:popUpTo="@id/navigation_home" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_navigation_notifications"
        app:destination="@id/navigation_notifications"
        app:launchSingleTop="true"
        app:popUpTo="@id/navigation_notifications" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_navigation_songs"
        app:destination="@id/navigation_songs"
        app:launchSingleTop="true"
        app:popUpTo="@id/navigation_songs" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_navigation_videos"
        app:destination="@id/navigation_videos"
        app:launchSingleTop="true"
        app:popUpTo="@id/navigation_videos" />
</navigation>
```

**STEP 4: Use global actions**

When you wrote

```
 NavigationUI.setupWithNavController (bottomNavigationView, navHostFragment.getNavController ());
```

then inside `setupWithNavController()` NavigationUI uses `bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener()` to navigate to proper fragments depending on id of the menu item that was clicked. It's default behavior is as I mentioned before. We will add our own implementation to it and use global actions to achieve our desired back press behavior.

Here is how you do it simply in `MainActivity`

```
 bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                int id = menuItem.getItemId();
                if (menuItem.isChecked()) return false;

                switch (id)
                {
                    case R.id.navigation_home :
                        navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_navigation_home);
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_images :
                        navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_navigation_images);
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_videos :
                        navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_navigation_videos);
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_songs :
                        navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_navigation_songs);
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_notifications :
                        navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_navigation_notifications);
                        break;
                }
                return true;

            }
        });
```

**FINAL STEP 5: Add your custom navigator to NavController**

Add your navigator as follow in your MainActivity. Make sure you are passing  `childFragmentManager` of the `NavHostFragment`.

```
navController.getNavigatorProvider().addNavigator(new StickyFragmentNavigator(this, navHostFragment.getChildFragmentManager(),R.id.nav_host_fragment));
```

Also add the navigation graph to `NavController` here as well using `setGraph()` method as shown below.

This is how my `MainActivity` looks like after **step 4** and **step 5**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
       
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_images, R.id.navigation_videos,R.id.navigation_songs,R.id.navigation_notifications)
                .build();
        NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        
        final NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        navController.getNavigatorProvider().addNavigator(new StickyFragmentNavigator(this, navHostFragment.getChildFragmentManager(),R.id.nav_host_fragment));
        navController.setGraph(R.navigation.mobile_navigation);
        
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView,navController);
        
        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                int id = menuItem.getItemId();
                if (menuItem.isChecked()) return false;

                switch (id)
                {
                    case R.id.navigation_home :
                        navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_navigation_home);
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_images :
                        navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_navigation_images);
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_videos :
                        navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_navigation_videos);
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_songs :
                        navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_navigation_songs);
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_notifications :
                        navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_navigation_notifications);
                        break;
                }
                return true;

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks actually i wanted to save the burrons clicked in the one of my fragments thanks for this one brother

Comment: have posted another question maybe you can understand better

Comment: I have read your new question and it is the same thing. You can update this question to make it more specific instead of creating a new post. But anyway I'll post a proper solution a bit later when I get free.

Comment: @KyleMutta sorry for making you wait for more than a week. I actually got stuck in finding a solution that would require least amount of code and shift from the navigation component library. But finally I was able to find one. Read the updated solution. Its a bit long but worth a read. hope it helps.

Comment: it shouldn't be that hard

Comment: Doesn't this lead to a bloat up of memory, since all the fragments have to be kept in memory?

Comment: @aligur Agreed, this solution only assumes that one doesn't wants to use ViewModel or other preferred way to save and reload state. Also the solution includes some extra steps to implement the mentioned navigation behavior (not asked by the OP) which are optional. In short the solution shows to replace the default navigator of NavigationUI with custom one. Simple as that :)

Comment: @SarahMultitasker Depends on the number of fragments and what each fragment contains. If you have 2 or 3 not so heavy fragment, no issues with that. Performance and memory efficiency of the app is subjective. If you measured it and all looks good, then it doesn't matter how many fragments are in memory at the same time.

Comment: I tried to import your code into my project and fixed all the issues, but I couldn't fix the one: "dispatchOnNavigatorBackPress()" is a unresolved reference. Checked out the fragmentManager.java file from Android and it indeed doesn't have such method. Only "dispatchOnHiddenChanged()" and "dispatchOnAttachFragment()". Any ways to fix this?

Comment: Good post. The issue with ```ViewModel``` retains data is in some uses cases it is injected into fragment, therefore it loses its state. It is possible to make this ```ViewModel``` as a singleton, but cases when you need the same ```ViewModel``` as a singleton and as a new instance are also not rare.

Comment: @SyedAhmedJamil 
You said 
(1) 
A -> B -> C -> D -> E
your back stack will have only
[A, E]
Its not true the back stack keeps all the fragments on the way until we use popupTo property nav graph xml file

(2) 
Could you please share a link to show the code for
 NavHostFragment's FragmentNavigator default implementation replaces the fragments whenever we navigate using FragmentTransaction.replace() which completely destroys the previous fragment and adds a new fragment

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure if this is the answer you are looking for but if you are concerned about managing state the modern way of managing state is by using something called a view model. View models are a component of the MVVM architecture. Their purpose is to hold and expose data to your fragment/activity to display. With the navigation architecture, if you store the data related to each fragment in this view model appropriately your state will be retained in the view model.

That being said I would personally suggest looking into MVVM architecture as well as view models specifically. Otherwise, a brute force for retaining state is by using the `savedInstance` state throughout fragments and manually saving and recovering important data.

Links: 
 - [Android View Model Component](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)
 - [Android architecture guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to prevent recreating the fragment upon clicking bottom nav view item twice. `bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener { /*Nothing to ignore reselection*/}`  after `NavigationUI.setupWithNavController (bottomNavigationView, navHostFragment.getNavController ());`