# RecyclerView with StaggeredGridLayoutManager in ViewPager, arranges items automatically when going back to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-architecture-navigation, staggeredgridlayoutmanager

I am using Navigation component in my App, using google Advanced Sample([here](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/main/NavigationAdvancedSample)).
my problem is when going back to a fragment, t**he scrolling position does not lost** but it rearranges items and moves highest visible items so that top of those item align to top of recyclerview. please see this:

[image]

before going to next fragment:

[image]

and after back to fragment:

[image]

this problem is matter because some times clicked item goes down and not seen until scroll down.
how to prevent this behavior?

please consider:

- this problem exist if using navigation component to change fragment. if start fragment using `supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()` or start another activity and then go to this fragment it is OK. but if I navigate to another fragment using navigation component this problem is exist.(maybe because of recreating fragment)
- also this problem exist if using fragment in ViewPager. i.e recyclerView is in a fragment that handle with ViewPagerAdapter and viewPager is in HomeFragment that opened with Navigation component. if recyclerView is in HomeFragment there is no problem.
- no problem with LinearLayoutManager. only with StaggeredGridLayoutManager.
- there is not difference if using ViewPager2 and also FragmentStatePagerAdapter
- I try to prevent recreate of fragment(by this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54581071/fragments-destroyed-recreated-with-jetpacks-android-navigation-components)) but not solved.

**UPDATE:**
**you can clone project with this problem from** [here](https://github.com/thawri1/MyStaggeredListSample)

Comment: I can't spend time on project setup, but if you can provide a functional demo which I can fork and run, then I can help.

Comment: @HarisDautović thanks for your respone. you can get that from this link:
https://github.com/thawri1/MyStaggeredListSample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `Navigation Component` + `ViewPager` + `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`, wrong `recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollOffset()` has been returned during `Fragment` recreate.

In general, all layout managers bundled in the support library already know how to save and restore scroll position, but in this case, we had to take responsibility for this.

```
class TestFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_test) {

    private val testListAdapter: TestListAdapter by lazy {
        TestListAdapter()
    }

    private var layoutManagerState: Parcelable? = null

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        postListView.apply {
            layoutManager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(
                2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL
            ).apply {
                gapStrategy = StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_MOVE_ITEMS_BETWEEN_SPANS
            }
            setHasFixedSize(true)

            adapter = testListAdapter
        }

        testListAdapter.stateRestorationPolicy = RecyclerView.Adapter.StateRestorationPolicy.PREVENT

    }

    override fun onPause() {
        saveLayoutManagerState()
        super.onPause()
    }

    override fun onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState)
        restoreLayoutManagerState()
    }

    private fun restoreLayoutManagerState () {
        layoutManagerState?.let { postListView.layoutManager?.onRestoreInstanceState(it) }
    }

    private fun saveLayoutManagerState () {
        layoutManagerState = postListView.layoutManager?.onSaveInstanceState()
    }
}
```

Source code: https://github.com/dautovicharis/MyStaggeredListSample/tree/q_65539771

Comment: thank you.
its working in sample project. but not in my real project!
In fact, I have already tried your solution in my real app but it did not solved the problem.
After your answer, I tried again. But I did not see any change.
I also copied almost whole sample files to real project but not see change too.
after that, I copy all my real app dependencies to sample app. now problem return to sample project!
after so many try and error I realize the problem is from Paging 3 library(just imported and not used)!

Comment: the dependency is:
implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:3.0.0-alpha11"

Comment: I am guessing exclude something from paging solves problem But I do not know what

Comment: It doesn't happen on latest stable version -> implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:2.1.2".

Comment: I know that. but version 3 and 2 is very different. and my app is almost ready to publish.
maybe I must create new issue for paging 3.

Comment: problem is from RecyclerView. paging library using alpha version of RecyclerView that have this problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65606959/10109704

Comment: my problem solved by using:
testListAdapter.stateRestorationPolicy = RecyclerView.Adapter.StateRestorationPolicy.PREVENT
and custom restoration logic

Comment: @HadiAhmadi Thank you. I can update the answer, but also, if you have permission to edit feel free to do it.

Comment: @HadiAhmadi Do we still need save and restore layoutManager state manually when using this new solution?

Answer (score 1):

The Navigation Component behavior is normal when you navigate from one fragment to another. I mean, `onDestroyView()` method from the previous fragment is executed, so it means that your view is destroyed, but not the fragment. Remembering that fragment has **two lifecycles** one for the fragment and another one for the view, There was a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=956&v=RS1IACnZLy4&feature=youtu.be) about it.

Also, there were issues registered in issue tracker in order to avoid this behavior in some cases and the GitHub issues:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/127932815
- https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/issues/530

The problem is that when you have fragment that is heavy to **recreate**, is easier to do not destroy it and just add one fragment. So, when you go back it is not recreated. But, for this behavior is not part of navigation component.

Solutions

- The easiest solution is to not use navigation component and work with the tradicional way, as you can see this works perfectly in you use case.
- You can use the traditional way just for this use case, and use the navigation component for other cases.
- You can inflate this view in an activity. So you are adding un activity
- But if the previous tree options is not possible. You can try the following:

  - If you are using viewModel, you can use [SaveState](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel-savedstate). Basically, it can save the data from your fragment, it is like a map data structure, so you can save positions from your list or recycler view. When go back to this fragment, get the position from this saveState object and use `scrollToPosition` method in order to add the real position.
  - Recycler view have methods for restore positions. You can see the uses cases for that, because first you need the data and then add the real position, for more details you can visit [this link](https://www.facebook.com/HailAndroidDevs/posts/222285346153647). This configuration for recycler view is useful also when you lose memory and you need to recreate the recycler view with asynchronous data.

Finally, if you want to understand more about how fragment works with navigation component, you can see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59232880/my-fragments-keep-recreating-whenever-i-reclick-or-navigate-to-the-next-fragment)

Comment: In fact, the scrolling position does not lost. just aligns most top items to top of recyclerview

Comment: I think it is aligning to the top because. It is adding the data again. So it is like the first time you open that fragment

Comment: the point is this behavior only exist in viewpager.

Comment: It will happen with any componente that has data. You can see the issue tracker and the GitHub page