# How to restore fragment when backpressed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I'm using navgraph with some fragments Fragment A --> Fragment B --> Fragment C as the navigation. When I navigate from Fragment A to Fragment B and press back, I see onCreateView  and then onViewCreated is called again in the Fragment A which results to render the fragment again and make the backend apis. I have a recyclerview in Fragment A which makes the fragment A to render recyclerview again.
Can someone tell me in navgraph how can I stop re-rendering Fragment A when back is pressed from Fragment B.

Thanks

Comment: This may help you, https://stackoverflow.com/a/59236146/9701793

Comment: have you tried `.addToBackStack` method in fragment transaction.

Comment: @rcs, Sorry I was out on weekend.. I will give it a try thanks.